# What's the intuition behind Rademacher complexity?

Tags: machine-learning

As stated, what exactly is the intuition behind Rademacher Complexity which is defined:

> Rademacher complexity captures the richness of a family of functions by measuring the degree to which a hypothesis set can fit random noise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard "intuition" is that the Rademacher complexity quantifies the ability of the function class $F$ to fit symmetric random noise: a low value (close to 0) means that this ability is limited (and hence the "capacity" of this class is bounded), while a high value (close to 1 for $\{-1,1\}$-valued classes) means that essentially any sequence of random signed bits has a perfect fit (and hence the capacity is unbounded).

To delve a bit deeper, it's always helpful to consider the extreme cases. Let $F$ be a collection of $\{-1,1\}$-valued functions on some large set $\Omega$, $|\Omega|=N\gg1$. What happens when $F$ consists of a single function $f$? What happens when $F=2^\Omega$ consists of *all* possible functions? You can also consider the cases where $|F|=2,3$ and look up "Massart's finite class lemma", which gives a bound for $|F|<\infty$ and is actually at the heart of more sophisticated (covering-number based) bounds.

Comment: What do you mean by "symmetric random noise"?

Comment: The Rademacher variables are symmetric random noise: are independent and take on +/-1 with equal probability.

Comment: @Aryeh How is capacity of a function class defined?

Comment: @1.. "capacity" is not a formally defined term and notice that I put it in quotes. Roughly speaking, it measures the ability of a function class to fit random noise. VC-dim is a worst-case measure of this, while Rademacher is more of an avergae-case measure.